# I got a 'NoSuchElementException' error when I ran this script on GitHub Actions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, github-actions

I encountered an error when running the script on GitHub Actions, but it worked fine when I ran the same script on my local system

```
@Test
public void update() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    driver().manage().window().maximize();
    driver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    driver().get("https://www.naukri.com/");
    logger().log(Status.INFO,driver().getTitle());
    addScreemshot();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebElement aa = driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login_Layer']"));
    putwaitclick(aa);
    logger().log(Status.INFO,"click on login button by wait");
    addScreemshot();
    logger().log(Status.INFO,"click on login layer");
    if (true) {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Enter your active Email ID / Username']"))
                .sendKeys("usename");
        addScreemshot();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        logger().log(Status.INFO,"Enter user name");
        driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Enter your password']"))
                .sendKeys("password");
        addScreemshot();
        logger().log(Status.INFO,"Enter password");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver().findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Login']")).click();
        addScreemshot();
        logger().log(Status.INFO,"click on login button");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        if (driver().getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase("https://www.naukri.com/mnjuser/homepage")) {
            logger().log(Status.INFO,"user logged in ");
            logger().log(Status.INFO,driver().getTitle());
            driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='view-profile-wrapper']/a")).click();
            logger().log(Status.INFO,"click on My profile ");
            logger().log(Status.INFO,driver().getCurrentUrl());
         
            String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"src/main/Resume/My_Resume _removed.pdf";

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='attachCV']"))
                    .sendKeys("C:/Users/mrshi/IdeaProjects/Page_object/src/main/Resume/My_Resume _removed.pdf");
            logger().log(Status.INFO,driver().getCurrentUrl());
            logger().log(Status.INFO,"resume updated");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            addScreemshot();
            String msg = driver().findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='msg']")).getText();
            logger().log(Status.INFO,msg);
            //clickByjavaScript("//*[@id='attachCV']");
            //uploadFile("Resume/My_Resume _removed.pdf");

        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("check your username and password");
    }
}
```

**this is the base implementation**

```
if (driver() == null) {
        if (System.getProperty("browser").equals("chrome")) {
            System.out.println("browser equal hai");
            System.out.println("----->"+System.getProperty("browser"));
            System.out.println("----->"+System.getProperty("envvalue"));

            options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setBrowserVersion("116");
            options.addArguments("--headless=new");
          // options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36");
            dr.set(new ChromeDriver(options));
            driver().manage().window().maximize();
            driver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
            driver().manage().deleteAllCookies();
        } else {
            EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
            options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
            options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36");
```

use selenium 4.11.0 version
Please make sure to replace "username" and "password" with your actual username and password values. Additionally, review the commented-out line for the user-agent and modify it as needed.

this is the github action error
[image]

Comment: GitHub Actions allows you to build a self-hosted agent, so please use that to analyze further what's wrong.